# Find constant of this inequality $\textbf{t}' \textbf{E}^b \textbf{t} \geq (\textbf{t}'\textbf{E} \textbf{t})^a$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, binomial-theorem, positive-definite

Let a vector $\textbf{t} \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $\textbf{E} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ positive semidefinite matrix. Given that
$$ \textbf{t}' \textbf{E}^b \textbf{t} \geq (\textbf{t}'\textbf{E} \textbf{t})^a,$$ 
$a = [0.5,1)$ and ' is the vector transpose. How can I obtain the real value of $b$?

Comment: Is $E$ a *fixed* matrix?  Are you trying to find the lowest possible value of $b$?  Did you mean to say that $a \in [0.5,1)$, which is to say that $a$ is a specific value satisfying $0.5\leq a<1$?

Comment: Is $t$ a fixed vector, or should the inequality hold for all $t$? If you intend the inequality to hold for all $t \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then this isn't possible unless $E = 0$. The left side is scales with $\|t\|^2$ while the right side scales with $\|t\|^{2a}$. So we can take $t$ such that $t'Et > 0$, and then shrink it by a constant factor to violate the inequality.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Exactly, $E$ and $a$ are fixed. I mean, they will be known and then I am trying to find the lowest value of $b$.

Comment: @Mauro then, as Jimmy says, no value of $b$ will work.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some matrices, there is no possible choice of $b$.

We can take, for example 
$$
E = \pmatrix{2\\&1/2}
$$
This then becomes the inequality
$$
2^bx^2 + 2^{-b}y^2 \geq (2x^2 + y^2/2)^a
$$
Setting $x=1,y=0$, we have the inequality
$$
2^b \geq 2^a \implies b \geq a
$$
On the other hand, setting $x=0,y=1$, we have the inequality
$$
2^{-b} \geq 2^{-a} \implies b \leq a
$$
which leaves us with $b = a$ as the only possibility.  Then, as the comment below shows, even this is won't give us the desired inequlity.

So, no value of $b$ will work here for any $a$.

Comment: And if we take $x = \tfrac{1}{2}$ and $y = 0$, we get $\tfrac{1}{4} \cdot 2^b \ge \tfrac{1}{2^a}$ which yields $a+b \ge 2$, which is impossible with the restrictions $a = b$ and $a \in [0.5,1)$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Aha! I was trying to think of something there.